# display certain characters in string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, character

I receive from an api service this string

> {\n  "modelColor": ["000019000031262"]\n}"}

how can I display only the numbers : "**000019000031262**" in a console log or alert message using Javascript?

Comment: Regex would be a good choice.

Comment: what is Regex im sorry?

Comment: Are you sure there is an extra trailing `}`?

Comment: See [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or similar

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String#match` to extract the wanted part.

```js
let str = '{\n "modelColor": ["000019000031262"]\n}"}';
let res = str.match(/\["(.*)"]/)[1]; // get first captured group
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```js
const str = `{\\n "modelColor": ["000019000031262"]\\n}"}`
const regex = /\[(.*)\]/gm;

console.log(regex.exec(str)[1])
```

But it seems most likely that the api is actually returning JSON (and that maybe you have clipped it). If so. Use JSON.parse to convert the string to an object